# Trusting SSL certificates stored in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" in c#

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, single-sign-on, adfs3.0

**Context:**

I'm trying to experiment wit ADFS SSO and followed this tutorial to first connect to Azure AD:

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/

**That worked.**

Then trying to make it connect to ADFS on our Win Server 2012 R2 following this other tutorial:

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/

and just as they say in this 3rd tutorial:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn660967.aspx

I get a SSL certificate error:

[image]

**Questions:**

I know I can bypass certificate validation or put special logic in **ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback** to code around this  but since I imported the certificate in my local machine "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"...:

1. ... why is my service still complaining about the certificate?
2. ... Is there a way to tell my C# service to accept ALL certificates
       in the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store?

NOTE: I did implement a **ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback** and that works but since we will get a whole bunch of clients sending us their ADFS certs, I would like to only have to import their certs in the cert store to have our service trust them.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you don't import it to your personal trusted root authority by mistake. Meanwhile, check further on the certificate to see if it requires intermediate certificates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put the root certificate inside the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store (not the certificate itself). If you open a certificate and go to certification path you will be able to view the root certificate.

To explain this further:

Every certificate has an issuer, and such issuer also has a certificate.

Usually the issuer is a Certification Authority (CA).

Such certificate (of the CA) might be signed by the CA itself (self-signed), or another parent CA.

So you have a parent/child relationship here. The root certificate is the certificate for the root issuer, i.e., the parent/grandparent of which certificate is self signed.

[image: The certification path tab]

In this example, the Administrator certificate is signed by the CA. And the CA certificate is self-signed. In this case, you would want to install the CA certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.

There are other factors that play a role when it comes to certificate validation. For example, a certificate has an expiry data after which it will be considered invalid.

Comment: wowow Yacoub, that is a very clear solution and explanation, thanks a milion! I think too many people bypass the self-signed certs issue by implementing a ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback while all they have to do is import the cert and the issuer cert!

Comment: What if I do not see the CA or any root, but just a one liner name...? I am facing this issue, even though it is added to trusted root.

Comment: @Koder101, that would be a self signed certificate

Comment: @YacoubMassad, Yes that is a self-signed certificate, but how can I make it fully trusted so that browser doesn't complain. I also followed this - 
http://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2012/03/13/sharepoint-2010-and-cert-trust-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssltls-secure-channel/
 -----------------------------------
except exporting the certificate which is not available in my case (already have that certificate). But still getting the issue. 
Any suggestions, please.

Comment: @Koder101, you can use the X509Chain class to check the certificate. Use the Build method first. And then check the ChainStatus element. This should give you more information on why the certificate has issues.